# Is fetching an object by String key be faster than a Key key? (GAE/J)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Thats pretty much the question. Are there any other concerns i should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

No. Fetching by key is faster than querying, but it doesn't matter what form the key is in.

Answer (score 0):

The only criteria in the [documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Keys) that I can find is on whether to use non-Key or Key is whether you have Entity Relations. If you do use Keys.